# Ansible in CentOS7 enabling systemctl service with {0..{{ansible_processor_cores}}} doesn't works

Tags: centos, ansible, graphite, graphite-carbon

I'm trying to enable carbon-aggregator with ansible in CentOS7 enabling systemctl service with ansible variable "ansible_processor_cores". And it doesn't works. 
Here is role example:

```
- name: enable carbon-aggregator
  service: 
    name: 'carbon-aggregator@{0..{{ansible_processor_cores -3}}}'
    enabled: yes
    state: started
    daemon_reload: yes
```

Carbon.conf.j2:

```
{% for aggr in range(ansible_processor_cores -2) %} 
[aggregator:{{aggr}}]
{% endfor %}
```

Error is:

> FAILED! => {"changed": false, "failed": true, "msg": "Unable to start
>   service carbon-aggregator@{0..1}: Job for
>   carbon-aggregator@\x7b0..1\x7d.service failed because the control
>   process exited with error code. See \"systemctl status
>   \"carbon-aggregator@\\x7b0..1\\x7d.service\"\" and \"journalctl
>   -xe\" for details.\n"}

As I see here is trying to enable some services that I didnt asked:

> carbon-aggregator@\x7b0..1\x7d.service

I don't know where they came from.
If I'll do that manually it works perfectly like that:

```
sudo systemctl enable carbon-aggregator@{0..1}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: with this module you specify only ONE service, this is not interpreted the way you think it is. You have to use with_items, to loop with ansible.

Comment: @papey Do you have any example like how it should looks for this specific example?

Comment: I'm digging to find a clean way to do this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To start up a number of services you could use a `with_sequence` loop.  See the [Loops](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_loops.html#looping-over-integer-sequences) documentation for details, although I believe that the documentation for `with_sequence` may be incorrect.

An example might look something like:

```
- name: enable carbon-aggregator
  service: 
    name: 'carbon-aggregator@{{ item }}'
    enabled: yes
    state: started
    daemon_reload: yes
  with_sequence: start=0 end={{ansible_processor_cores-1}}
```

On a system with four cores, the above loop would call the `service` module four times, with `name:` set to `carbon-aggregator@0`,  `carbon-aggregator@1`, `carbon-aggregator@2`, and `carbon-aggregator@3`.